# ECDSA: How to retrieve a non-random k

Tags: dsa, modular-arithmetic

I have a question regarding the random $k$ number of ECDSA encryption. As far as I know, it is possible to retrieve $k$ (and thus the private key) from two signed messages if both used the same $k$. This was done for the PlayStation 3 hack. I'm now trying to reproduce it in Python, using [this library](https://github.com/warner/python-ecdsa).

My problem is that the hack only works in some cases (at least I think so). I've not been able to reproduce it, so I hoped you could help me.

Initially we have two equations:
$$
s_1 = k^{-1} * (z_1 + y) \mod n \\
s_2 = k^{-1} * (z_2 + y) \mod n \\
$$
(where $y = r*\mathrm{privatekey}$)

We want to get rid of y and figure out k. In all explanations I've seen so far, they'll do something like this:
$$ \begin{align}
s_1 - s_2 &= k^{-1} * (z_1 + y) - k^{-1} * (z_2 + y) \\
s_1 - s_2 &= k^{-1} * (z_1 - z_2) \\
\frac{s_1 - s_2}{z_1 - z_2} &= k^{-1} \\
k &= \frac{z_1 - z_2}{s_1 - s_2} \\
\end{align} $$

This doesn't work in my code, because in this hack, the modulo operation at the beginning is just ignored. If I we don't ignore it, the equation should look like this:
$$
i*n + s_1 = k^{-1} * (z_1 + y) \\
j*n + s_2 = k^{-1} * (z_2 + y) \\
$$

I got rid of the modulo by adding $x*n$ to the left side, where x (i or j) is unknown. With this equation I'll just do the same thing as above but keep the $+ x*n$:
$$ \begin{align}
i*n + s_1 - j*n - s_2 &= k^{-1} * (z_1 - z_2) \\
\frac{s_1 - s_2 + n*(i-j)}{z_1 - z_2} &= k^{-1} \\
k &= \frac{z_1 - z_2}{s_1 - s_2 + n*(i-j)} \\
\end{align} $$

Obviously we do not know $i$ and $j$. We can ignore them if $i = j$ (as we did in the first calculation), which is only the case when $z_1$ and $z_2$ are close together or $k^{-1}$ is very small (so that it pulls the result down and therefore prevents $z_1$ or $z_2$ from making too much difference).

In theory $k^{-1}$ is pretty small (since it's $\frac{1}{k}$) and therfore the exploit works. But in practice I've seen that $k^{-1}$ is not used, but instead the smallest inverse modulo of $k \mod n$ that is a whole number is used. This number can be really large, which actually amplifies the difference between $z_1$ and $z_2$, making $i-j$ pretty large. With this implementation, I can't use the exploit as explained in theory, because I never get my exact $k$.

My questions are:

- Mathematically, is there another way to retrieve $k$, even if the $k^{-1}$ part is really large? Maybe using some inverse modulo?
- Why is it that many implementations use the inverse modulo instead of $k^{-1}$? (I've seen it in two libraries so far)
- Why doesn't it work when I change the implementation to use $k^{-1}$?

Since this is part of an assignment for Uni, retrieving $k$ still has to work somehow. But I already spent too much time on it without any results.
Any gurus out there that can help me? :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you are being confused by what $k^{-1}$ means.  It doesn't mean "interpret $k$ as a real number, plug it into a calculator, and hit the $1/x$ button".

When we use the $k^{-1}$ notation, what we mean to say is that $a = k^{-1}$ is equivalent to saying that $a \times k = 1$.

You will say "doesn't that mean doing exactly what a calculator does?".  Well, it would, if the multiplication was performed in the field of the reals.  However, we're doing everything modulo $n$ (within the field $GF(n)$, as $n$ is prime), and so the multiplication is done modulo $n$; hence we really have $a \times k = 1 \pmod{n}$.

In this context, when we write $k^{-1}$, we really do intend the modular inverse.  And, when we derive $k = \frac{z_1 - z_2}{s_1 - s_2}$, we're not ignoring the modulo operation; it's been assumed implicitly; what we really mean is $k = (z1 - z2) \times (s_1 - s_2)^{-1} \bmod n$, there $(s_1 - s_2)^{-1}$ is the multiplicative inverse (modulo $n$) of $s_1 - s_2$.

When you derive $k = \frac{z_1 - z_2}{s_1 - s_2 + n*(i-j)}$, well, since everything is done modulo $n$, including the internal additions, we effectively have $n=0$ (because, modulo $n$, those are the value), and so $i$ and $j$ drop out, and we're left with the original derivation.

Since you explicitly asked questions, I'll answer them (even if they ought to be obvious once the above has been clarified):

> Mathematically, is there another way to retrieve $k$, even if the $k^{−1}$ part is really large? Maybe using some inverse modulo?

Yes, an inverse modulo is precisely what you're looking for.

> Why is it that many implementations use the inverse modulo instead of $k^{−1}$? (I've seen it in two libraries so far)

The inverse modulo that the libraries do is what is meant by $k^{-1}$

> Why doesn't it work when I change the implementation to use $k^{−1}$?

The mathematics of ECDSA assume that the math works out in one specific field (the field $GF(n)$); if you do the computations in a different field (say, the field of real numbers), well, it won't work.

Comment: thinking about it, i actually learned most of this in my first semester (discret mathematics). this makes me feel bad, knowing that i should've been able to solve it on my own :/ but thanks a lot for clearing things up